# cs50 weak 4 reflect problem, a problem in the output where the first row of each column is always zeros

Tags: c, cs50, swap

When running cheak50, I encounter some errors.  when I test the code on an image, it works correctly and reflects the image. The issue is that the first row of each column always contains zeros, despite the fact that it should be taking values.

the test below is using 3x3 image

```
Cause
expected "255 0 0\n255 0...", not "0 0 0\n255 0 0..."
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)
second row: (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)
third row: (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 2 2...
checking for output "255 0 0\n255 0 0\n255 0 0\n0 255 0\n0 255 0\n0 255 0\n0 0 255\n0 0 255\n0 0 255\n"...
```

#### Expected Output:

```
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
```

#### Actual Output:

```
0 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
```

#### the code

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //this is where the reflected image gonna be
    RGBTRIPLE reflected[height][width];
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 1 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
            reflected[h][w] = image[h][width-1 - w];
        }
    }
    //copying from the reflected to the image
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
           image[h][w] = reflected[h][w];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I think it is something related to the for loops.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger and watch your variables change while you step through the instructions. For this you must provide a `main` function that calls your function and provides test data (as you have already been asked to show in your previous question)

Comment: The first loop never sets `reflected[h][0]` (due to the initializer `w = 1`), but the second loop _does_ use `reflected[h][0]`. Can you explain that?

Comment: Your last pixel in second row looks strange. Is that a copy&paste from the test website or did you retype?

Comment: "it works correctly and reflects the image" I doubt that. Do you look closely at the first column when checking your result? That error is likely to be present in all your resulting images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments section you have to fix `w` initializer in the following line:

```
for (int w = 1 ; w < width ; w++)
```

To:

```
for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
```

I think this is enough:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

void reflect(int height, int width, int image[height][width])
{
    //this is where the reflected image gonna be
    int reflected[height][width];
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
            reflected[h][w] = image[h][width -1 -w];
        }
    }
    //copying from the reflected to the image
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
           image[h][w] = reflected[h][w];
        }
    }
    return;
}

void print_image(int height, int width, int image[height][width])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        printf ("\t");
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            printf ("%d ", image[j][i]);

        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main ()
{
    int image[9][3] =
    {{255, 0, 0,},
     {255, 0, 0,},
     {255, 0, 0,},
     {0, 255, 0,},
     {0, 255, 0,},
     {0, 255, 0,},
     {0, 0, 255,},
     {0, 0, 255,},
     {0, 0, 255,}};

    printf ("image = \n");
    print_image (9, 3, image);

    reflect(9, 3, image);

    printf ("reflected = \n");
    print_image (9, 3, image);
}
```

Is that the expected output?

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
image = 
    255 0 0 
    255 0 0 
    255 0 0 
    0 255 0 
    0 255 0 
    0 255 0 
    0 0 255 
    0 0 255 
    0 0 255 

reflected = 
    0 0 255 
    0 0 255 
    0 0 255 
    0 255 0 
    0 255 0 
    0 255 0 
    255 0 0 
    255 0 0 
    255 0 0
```